# preg_reaplce: ¿Como hacer que los puntos se interpreten?

Tags: php, regex

buenas noches.

Estoy desarrollando un script con php, donde se pueden crear posts. En una parte de este necesito que los links en texto (example.com) se reemplacen con "example.com" al ingresar un comando.

Para esto desarrolle el siguiente código:

```
$envio = preg_replace('/web:(\w+)/', '<a href="$1">$1</a>, $envio);
```

Hasta aca todo correcto, efectivamente al colocar web:example.org example.org se convierte en un link... El problema es que al toparse con un punto, este deja de reemplazarlo, es decir, solo queda "example" con un link que apunta a "/example" y no "example.org". Omite completamente los puntos.

¿Como podría hacer que los puntos se interpreten sin problemas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes intentar lo siguiente

```
$status_text = preg_replace('|([\w\d]*)\s?(https?://([\d\w\.-]+\.[\w\.]{2,6})[^\s\]\[\<\>]*/?)|i', '$1 <a href="$2">$3</a>', $status_text);
echo $status_text;
```

O esto para que sea más fácil de leer y más ordenado

```
$m = '|([\w\d]*)\s?(https?://([\d\w\.-]+\.[\w\.]{2,6})[^\s\]\[\<\>]*/?)|i';
$r = '$1 <a href="$2">$3</a>';

$status_text = preg_replace($m,$r,$status_text);
echo $status_text;
```

Comment: tu respuesta fue perfecta!

Me ha servido, y en mi caso la implementé de la siguiente forma:

    $envio = preg_replace('|([\w\d]*)\s?(web?:([\d\w\.-]+\.[\w\.]{2,6})[^\s\]\[\<\>]*/?)|i', '$1 <a href="https://$3">$3</a>', $envio); 

Ya que necesitaba que funcione cuando se usaba web:example.org y modifiqué el $2 por $3 añadiendole https:// ya que las urls se ingresan sin el https:// 

Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Qué bueno que te sirvió. Saludos!